# mod_cache module seems not loaded in apache

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, apache2

I have a docker container with apache and I'm trying to set `mod_cache` configuration.
It seems like `mod_cache` is not loaded at all (is not in list here `apachectl -M`).

Is my logic correct? What can I do in this case?

Comment: Is the module installed in the OS running in your container?  If so, did you enable it?

Comment: Thank you, @GerardH.Pille. The OS is Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). How can I check the module is installed?

Comment: /usr/local/apache2/modules# ls -> mod_cache.so, mod_cache_disk.so exist here. I conclude the module is installed.

Comment: /usr/local ??  Did you have a good reason not to install Debian's version?  Otherwise you could have done a "a2enmod cache".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module is loaded now after using `cache_module` instead of `mod_cache` in `APACHE_MODULES` env variable (rancher configuration).